# TextView above and exactly centered of the image view works perfectly but in the case high end device the TextView is slightly up. Why?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, imageview

I make the single_row.xml for the custom adapter which works perfectly on several devices but in the case of HighEnd device , the TextVIew is slightly up from the center. Why ??Please Help..

**[Image Link to understand the question Clearly](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rz0wY2ajPmY/VeG3c5_o86I/AAAAAAAACVg/dugSxb_oIR0/s1600/ask.jpg)**

single_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="6dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title text here"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:id="@+id/textViewNumbering"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="description"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="imageLink"
        android:id="@+id/textViewImageLink"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textViewDescription"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you tell me which id refers to circle and number?

Comment: if the circe is a png image and the numbers are text, i suggest wrapping the Textview for the numbers inside a FrameLayout so you can  easy center the inside the circle using MarginTop="whatever dpi" , MarginLeft="whatever dpi" as the list items are all equal height

Comment: Also just use (android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewSingleRow") you dont need all those other alignments .Then you can use PaddingLeft and PaddingTop to position when next to the circle

Answer (score 0):

Finally done for the high end devices too..

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:text="1"
    android:padding="26dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/textViewNumbering"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageViewSingleRow"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```